# getting LLDB to follow pointers to templates

Tags: c++, templates, lldb, clion

I am trying to follow pointers to templates on LLDB. I keep failing, as in (names changed to protect the guilty):

```
>  (lldb) expr *(p->q->r)  
(x::y) $5 = {
    x::z<t::u> = {

...

> (lldb) expr p->q->r->x::z<t::u> 
error: 'x::z' is not a member of class 'x::y' 
(lldb)
```

There's **got to be** a way to do it, since the Clion IDE (using LLDB as its debugger) lets me click on such links as deeply as they go, template or no template. So how is this done in bare LLDB?

(yes, I looked high&low for documentation)

Comment: The expression parser uses clang to parse & JIT the expressions you provide it.  So you should be able to access it with the same code you would use in C++.  What error did you get from that?  Clion probably uses the API equivalent of the `frame variable` command to print variables.  You might try playing around with that.

Comment: Also, if you can post a complete toy example that shows the problem we can be of more help.  It's hard to say what's going on from this little snippet.